# can we create android project below api level 14

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

i want make android project which must be run in below API level 14, is it possible? how can we create emulator its? now, i'm not able to do this, if you have any idea share with me.

Comment: Search on google.

Comment: do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can make an Android project which must be run in below API level 14:

Step1: Create a normal project using Android Studio (MinSDK: 15)

Step2: Update your build.gralde: minSDKVersion to lower than 14 (i.e: 9), targetSDKVersion to 14 and compileSDKVersion to 14:

[image]

Later, you have to remove other stuffs like Themes, support library, etc.

2. You can download a emulator which lowest API version is 10: 
   [image]

Comment: Yes, just remove them. And your Activity should extends Activity, not extends AppCompatActivity anymore

Comment: i think it will create problem in api level 14 above

Comment: and when we go to create emulator below 14 all are showing deprecated , so how can i download it, i have same issue before some day

Comment: AppCompat libraries use some classes, methods which are available on API > 14 only, hence, they should be removed. You can google to download emulator images. I.e https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/android-237-gingerbread-x86-emulator-system-image